Can I deduce the saturation current of a transformer from the rated wattage and maximum frequency?
I have an SMPS transformer EE10, but am not sure about the saturation current it has, I tried doing some internet research, all what I can get is this so far :

I am trying to deduce the saturation current as following, but I am not sure if this sequence of logical steps is true. That's my main question. The other question, can I know that using LCR meter by providing a bias current to the transformer and watch when the inductance starts to drop?
I assume that the transformer is working on the boundary between CCM and DCM so that all the stored energy is transferred to the load, i.e. no energy is stored for the next cycle. Then the total energy transferred per cycle is
$$ \frac{1}{2}LI_{peak}^{2} $$
so energy transferred per second is
$$ \frac{1}{2}LI_{peak}^{2}\cdot F, $$
where \$F\$ is the number of cycles per second.
Thus, power, which is 3 watts, equals
$$ \frac{1}{2}LI_{peak}^{2}\cdot F $$
Solving for \$ I_{peak}\$ assuming the max frequency that the transformer can handle, which is 500 kHZ, yields 72.23 mA. Was that correct? Otherwise, if the saturation current is not mentioned explicitly in the datasheet and that is not correct process for calculating it from given data only, was the above-mentioned procedure correct for measuring the saturation current?

Use the minimum frequency.

You may be interested in saturation flux density, not current. When a transformer saturates, the current will increase greatly. Frequency and voltage, along with number of turns, core area, and material saturation characteristics all play a part.

The best is to measure the saturating current with a simple test setup. Look at slide 138 of my APEC 2018 seminar and reproduce the circuit with your transformer primary-side connected as the D.U.T. The best is to bake the core at its operating temp (usually close to 80-100 °C) while running this experiment. It is good practice to characterize magnetic elements (inductors or transformers) to determine a safe operating margin.
